# Django + nginx, only homepage works

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I don't understand this behavior coming from django running on gunicorn with static file hosting and port forwarding from nginx.

project directory tree:

```
.
├── myproj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── pages
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── pages
│   │       └── index.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── pages
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

pages/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('static-home/', views.index, name='static-home'),
    ]
```

myproj/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('pages/', include('pages.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

If I `python manage.py runserver` then everything works as expected at these URIs

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static-home/ 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/ 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/static-home/
```

If I dockerize using gunicorn + nginx
( as described in this blog post: https://blog.skindc.co.uk/dockerise-django-and-static-files-with-nginx/ )

Then I see a different behavior

```
good:      http://<docker-machine-ip>/
nginx 404: http://<docker-machine-ip>/static-home/
good:      http://<docker-machine-ip>/pages/
good:      http://<docker-machine-ip>/pages/static-home/
```

I will add any other info if requested, but in the interest of keeping the post succinct all my docker files, docker compose, nginx.conf, et cetera are the same as that shown in the tutorial linked above.

Why is it that I can add all urls from pages at `<docker-machine-ip>/pages/`, but I can only add the home page from pages at `<docker-machine-ip>/` and nothing else?

Comment: Did you set permission for your statics path ?

Comment: @ArashHatami I'm just running `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`, which automatically should provide default permissions, no? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Check permissions manually `ls -las`

Comment: You are probably running outdated container.